# php - Improvement of coding for function which insert into database with prepared statements with insert to 1 to 10 columns

Tags: php, mysql, function, prepared-statement, custom-function

I am relatively new in PHP programming and currently, I am building a website which has a lot of inserts into the database, so I decided to make one function which will make my job easier. Because I have a variable number of columns to insert into, I tried to make a function which allows that.

This is what I got so far:

```
function insertIntoDatabaseWithIdReturn($table_name, $array_of_columns, $array_of_insert_values) {
    require "dbconn3.script.php";
    // Generating variable types
    $variable_types = implode("", array_map(function($val){return gettype($val)[0];}, $array_of_insert_values));
    // MySQL query buiilder
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (";
    $column_list = "";
    $checkVariable = is_array($array_of_columns);
    if ($checkVariable) {
        foreach ($array_of_columns as $column_name) {
            $column_list .= $column_name." ";
        }
        $column_list_corrected = str_replace(" ", ", ", trim($column_list)).")";
        $sql .= $column_list_corrected." VALUES (";
        $valuesQ = "";
        $numberOfColumns = count($array_of_columns);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfColumns; $i++) {
                $valuesQ .= "? ";
        }
        $valuesQ_corrected = str_replace(" ", ", ", trim($valuesQ)).")";
        $sql .= $valuesQ_corrected;
        // MySQL query performer
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($numberOfColumns == 2) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 3) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 4) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2], $array_of_insert_values[3]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 5) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2], $array_of_insert_values[3], $array_of_insert_values[4]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 6) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2], $array_of_insert_values[3], $array_of_insert_values[4], $array_of_insert_values[5]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 7) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2], $array_of_insert_values[3], $array_of_insert_values[4], $array_of_insert_values[5], $array_of_insert_values[6]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 8) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2], $array_of_insert_values[3], $array_of_insert_values[4], $array_of_insert_values[5], $array_of_insert_values[6], $array_of_insert_values[7]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 9) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2], $array_of_insert_values[3], $array_of_insert_values[4], $array_of_insert_values[5], $array_of_insert_values[6], $array_of_insert_values[7], $array_of_insert_values[8]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } elseif ($numberOfColumns == 10) {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values[0], $array_of_insert_values[1], $array_of_insert_values[2], $array_of_insert_values[3], $array_of_insert_values[4], $array_of_insert_values[5], $array_of_insert_values[6], $array_of_insert_values[7], $array_of_insert_values[8], $array_of_insert_values[9]);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    mysqli_rollback($conn);
                } else {
                    return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                }
                mysqli_commit($conn);
            } else {
                echo "<div class=\"submit-form-success-message\"><p>Inserting into more than 10 columns is not supported.</p></div>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= $array_of_columns.") VALUES (?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $variable_types, $array_of_insert_values);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                mysqli_rollback($conn);
            } else {
                return mysqli_insert_id($conn);
            }
            mysqli_commit($conn); 
        }
    }
}
```

This script works well, but I am interested if it can be improved somehow. And if it can support more than 10 column insertion but without repeating code over and over with growing number of variables.

Comment: Looks like some HTML spilled into that mess of a function. Maybe look at existing approaches with ORMs? Use some sort of model entity? Don't combine "view" stuff in a  function that is about inserting? Besides the obvious "DRY" failures... the whole column number repeating nonsense.

Comment: HTML is for error reporting. I could improve function to be without it. But I am more interested in PHP improvement. I also do not like the DRY moment, but for now, I don't see the rightful approach to get rid of it.

Comment: Not trying to be overly critical but it's simply bad code. It fails to leverage OOP concepts. I don't want to discourage you, we all start someplace. Ignoring the fundamental issues, we *can* improve your existing code. Why the two arrays? One for columns and one for values? Why not an associative array? Then, rewrite it with out regard to `numberOfColumns` - you can write the function so that count is not relevant.

Comment: You are an expert, so I like to hear your opinion. I am still not quite familiar with OOP or OOP PHP, it is still hard for me to grasp it, so I am using a procedural approach. I didn't think about the associative array approach, but it has more sense it the way of improvement. I will try to change that.

Comment: For example `$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (".implode(', ', $fields).") VALUES (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($fields), '?')).")";` or similar. More elegant but as you say, very procedural.

Comment: Suggest reading up on [design patterns](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (PoEAA is great) and  general OOP concepts. A great way to learn is to use existing code libraries, then explore their source code. For example [Doctrine2](https://github.com/doctrine/orm), [Propel](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel3), maybe some basic Active Record code...

Comment: Thank you for an idea. I will try to implement it into my function. And I will surely check those links you suggested me.

Comment: Can you explain me function of the {} around $table? Is it the same as concatenation or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197521/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-user3120612).